# Applying a pixel shader to a ViewPort3D

Tags: wpf, pixel-shader

I'm new to pixel shaders, and I'm trying to apply an underwater-effect to my 3d scene. I can apply it to an image and animate it easily enough, but not to my ViewPort3D. The computer just hangs when calling BeginAnimation on the effect being applied to the Viewport3D. Is this something that cannot be done in WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little digging I learned that pixel shaders are only applied to 2 dimensional types, like images. So what I would need is called a vertex shader, which for WPF, there are none.